How are wires in ceiling connected to switches in the wall?
In the master bedroom of our house there are two pairs of wires coming out of the ceiling. Each pair is made up of one black and one red wire wrapped in blue. Neither wire is capped, just cut (and, of course, no current is running through them). These wires are certainly meant for two small light fixtures on the ceiling.
On the wall are two light switches that currently don't control anything in the bedroom, so I assume they are meant for these two pairs of wires in the ceiling. When I take off the switch plate I see four bundles of wires coming into the switch box. Two of the bundles have three wires (black, white, ground) and the other two bundles have four wires (black, white, red, ground). The grounds from all four bundles are connected with a wire nut out of which two ground wires go to each of the switches. The black wires from all four bundles are connected with a wire nut out of which two black wires go to each of the switches. The four white wires are connected with a wire nut and no white wires are connected to the switches. The two red wires go directly to each of the switches.
Two questions:

Am I correct in assuming these switches are meant for the wires in the ceiling?
How can I fix the wiring so each switch controls the wires in the ceiling?




no ... do not assume anything


Thanks @jsotola, I added the diagram directly

Assuming your pictures are correct, you should have white and ground wires there too.  You'll need to trace back to where the wires get lost.  Pictures of the wires may get more feedback.  Note that to power a light, you will need a red (switched hot) and white (neutral) wire.  The black (always hot) is useless to you for a switched light.  It would also help to know if you have access above the ceiling (e.g. an attic).

@mdfst13 I apologize, in the diagram the green is the ground and the gray is the white (neutral) wire. Is it possible the wiring is in the configuration it is in because the wires in the ceiling weren't being used and it was intended to be modified once the lights were installed?

Right.  I'm saying that if you only have black and red in the ceiling, you've lost your white and green wires somewhere.  Yes, it's entirely possible that they started to pull wires and stopped.  It's still wrong, they should bring the entire cable to the light fixture, not just two wires.  Someone will have to trace the wires back to figure out what happened.  It might be easier and certainly would be safer to have an electrician do it (or run new cable).  It's also conceivable that there was something 240V up there and those wires have nothing to do with the switches.

No chance one or both switches controls a wall outlet?

When two switches control one device/circuit(light/s or receptacles/outlets), they usually have three wires(plus ground) connected to them(three ways) and at each door/opening into a room/hallway.  Your switch diagram is for two different devices.  Pictures of how the switches are wired will help.
